# Run code once upon entering page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm running this code when entering a page:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
     {
         base.OnAppearing();

         Title = wasteObject.WasteType;

         foreach (var i in wasteDescription)
         {
             if (i.description_Id == wasteObject.Waste_Id)
             {
                 await viewModel.getDescription(i.wasteImage, i.sortName, i.wasteDescription, myWebView, (error) => 
                 {
                     if(error != null)
                     {
                         DisplayAlert("Problem", "Not possible", "Ok");
                     }
                 });
             }
         }

     }
```

The issue I'm having is that when I leave that page and get back to it. It has created 2 blocks with text (same text in both blocks). So what I wanna do is to run the code once to prevent more than one block of text to show.

Appreciate all the help, thanks.

Comment: Consider adding a boolean field `HasRun` to the page. Then if `false` set it to `true`. If already `true` exit the method without running the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @mjwills said in comment,
use boolean field to indicate if the code is already executed. 
Declare field outside the method OnAppearing

```
private bool isTextBlockCreated = false;
```

Then put the code that needs to be run only once in condition check with isTextBlockCreated

```
if(!isTextBlockCreated)
{
    foreach (var i in wasteDescription)
         {
             if (i.description_Id == wasteObject.Waste_Id)
             {
                 await viewModel.getDescription(i.wasteImage, i.sortName, i.wasteDescription, myWebView, (error) => 
                 {
                     if(error != null)
                     {
                         DisplayAlert("Problem", "Not possible", "Ok");
                     }
                 });
             }
         }

    isTextBlockCreated = true;
}
```

That should stop running it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

As @LeRoy said you can run it in the constructor that runs Init which calls viewModel.getDescription()  .

```
protected override async void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
            if (BindingContext is MyPageViewModel viewModel)
            {
                        foreach (var i in wasteDescription)
             {
            if (i.description_Id == wasteObject.Waste_Id)
                 {
                     await viewModel.getDescription(i.wasteImage, i.sortName, i.wasteDescription, myWebView, (error) => 
                     {
                         if(error != null)
                         {
                             DisplayAlert("Problem", "Not possible", "Ok");
                         }
                     });
                 }
            }
```

The other way to do it , is that since you have OnAppearing there is also OnDisappearing , and then you can remove the blocks which has been added by the Appearing.

Comment: `async void` is a bad idea for multiple reasons

Comment: It is totally acceptable in case of events. 
In anycase when he will do it on OnAppearing , he will be making async void too.

Comment: constructor is not an event handler

Comment: Anyway the idea here is that he wants it to run once , and one way to do is it do it from the constuctor. eventhough the books says not to do it , if that solves his issue why not ? After all for me there are many problems in his code , starting from passing the webview down to the viewModel.

Comment: Doesnt work, there is no information that shows up. @AhmadElMadi

Comment: Do you get the info when you debug it ?

Comment: No, its null. Its not null in the OnAppearing though. @AhmadElMadi

Comment: Ok that means you are using a framework like Prism.  and I did not load the viewmodel yet . 
In this case try to do it OnBindingContextChanged, this also happens once . 
I have updated my answer.